# Maven trouble with JDK 8 : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, build

Apologies if my question is a duplicate of any other items previously mentioned here .

I have the following configuration :

Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit
    JDK 1.8u45
    Maven v3.3

I am trying to package my code into a deployable war.

The war gets created succesfully , but on accessing it on my browser , I am running into Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 errors.

On Googling around I saw that this is due to a mismatch in installed JDK and the maven-compiler level.

But in my case , both are the same. -> JDK 1.8 and maven-compiler version 3.3 with source and target 1.8.

What can I do to get my build to compile successfully ?

Outputs of some helpful commands :

mvn -v

```
root@labuser-OptiPlex-3010:/# mvn -v 
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.3 
Java version: 1.8.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation 
Java home: /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_45/jre Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8 OS name: "linux", version: "3.16.0-43-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: You may think that your server in running Java 8, but clearly it is not...

Comment: Oracle JDK is the only version of java installed on it ..

That is corroborated by the output of java -version : 

root@labuser-OptiPlex-3010:/# java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: Agree with @SteveC. Check your server runtime, JAVA_HOME path and server config files. What's your server btw ?

Comment: I bet there's some version of OpenJDK < 8 on it somewhere, possibly embedded in your IDE.

Comment: ok this is java in your path, but your server might be using some other version. Is it a tomcat ? Are you running it in an IDE like eclipse intellij ?

Comment: @sashok_bg yes. my server is tomcat. I'm not using any IDE on my linux build machine. It just has JDK 8 , maven and the checked-out code.

Comment: How did you install Tomcat? If you did apt-install then it would have sucked down an OpenJDK as a dependency

Comment: @SteveC I extracted the Tomcat 64 bit tar locally and set CATALINA_HOME environment variable.

Comment: `find /usr -name java`

Comment: Does your application contain any applets?

Comment: Does Tomcat start up correctly. If there is a stack trace it may be useful to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned you can successfully create the war with maven, it sounds like JDK 8 is being used as expected during the build. The problem is your server is apparently running using an older version of Java. Although you only installed JDK 8 yourself, you must have already had an older version of Java on your computer. Make sure JAVA_HOME is set to JDK 8 and that your server sees that version properly. See if you have a JRE_HOME env variable set as well, and point it to JDK 8 as well.

Comment: I've checked the environment variables :

root@labuser-OptiPlex-3010:/# printenv JAVA_HOME

/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_45

root@labuser-OptiPlex-3010:/# printenv JRE_HOME

/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_45/jre

Comment: Check the version that tomcat sees using /path/to/tomcat/catalina.sh version

Answer (score 0):

`mvn -v` will tell you what Java version maven is using. Run that in your console, it will probably show you that it uses the wrong Java version.

Comment: Hmmm, okay, so maven is doing things right then.
You mentioned running Tomcat as an application server. Are you sure Tomcat is using the right Java version also?
See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287502/which-java-version-does-tomcat-use

Answer (score 0):

```
I got the solution by running :

<tomcat-root-dir> / bin > catalina.bat version.
```

It showed that the JDK on my machine was JDK1.7 where as the one used to compile the WAR was 1.8.

Thanks to everyone for their inputs.